# Is it weird to say $A \in B \in C$?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, notation

I've just noticed that I've never seen any text say $A \in B \in C$, which is why when writing it myself it immediately looked weird.

For context, I was proving a result about the topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by a basis $\mathcal{B}$. In particular, the fact that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{i \in \mathcal{A}} U_i \in \mathcal{T}$. I came to a line that said:

> Then $\exists i$ such that $x \in U_i$ and $U_i \in \mathcal{T}$.

In my own proof I had written

> $x \in U_i \in \mathcal{T}$.

Why has the proof been split into $x \in U_i$ and $U_i \in \mathcal{T}$? Is there any purpose for this?

Comment: It's weird because $\in$ is not a transitive relation. On the other hand, $\le$ and $\subseteq$ are, so $a \le b \le c$ and $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are often written as such.

Comment: Sure, you could write it (but it is not suggested).  Let $A$ be a set, $B=\mathcal{P}(A)$ be the power set of $A$ and $C=\mathcal{P}(B)$, the power set of $B$.  But, as @lastresort mentions, the relation shouldn't be considered transitively.

Comment: @lastresort I understand that it's not correct in general, but in some cases, such as this one and the case that Michael Burr has given, it seems to hold true. Though, thanks for pointing that out, that may be the reason it looks so weird.

Comment: @IrregularUser I didn't say that it is incorrect, it's just weird.

Comment: @lastresort Yep, I was just making a small comment on the correctness of it (coming from your comment)... however even in this case I'm not sure if it's correct. Will post an answer.

Comment: I think $x\in U_i \in T$ works fine. I read it as $x\in U_i$ and $U_i \in T$, but sure, $x\in T$ is meaningless here, so the transitivity messes things up if you do such an interpretation. Compare with the following: $x\in U_i \ni y$. That is surely not read in any transitive fashion, rather at each connective separately. I suppose in the end, it is a matter of type-checking what is written on the reader's end, and writing down things unambiguously on the writer's.

Comment: @A.Sh I was indeed trying to go for conciseness (resisting the urge to say compactness since that's not necessarily the case here!), which is why this question sprung to mind. However, if it's technically incorrect then I'd rather skip it altogether (in some cases it seems to be perfectly fine however).

Comment: @A.Sh I would write that as $x,y\in U_i$, because it generalizes to three or more more easily. (Not that it's _wrong_ to write it that way.)

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger If you're writing on paper, you could generalise to as many as you want using A.Sh's notation by rotating the $x_i \in$ around the $U_i$ and writing small enough so that they fit together (I've seen lecturers do this before and it's pretty funny).

Comment: @AkivaWeinberger I also write like that, but I have seen what I wrote down above several times before too. I have also seen "$x\in U_i$ and $y\in U_i$", but that just feels like a waste of space…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not any more weird than writing $a<b<c$, although *strictly* speaking we should not do that either.   However, since its generally understood to mean $a<b$ and $b<c$ it is a convenient abbreviation.

We do often write $a\in B\subset C$ with the understanding that this means $a\in B$ and $B\subset C$, and therefore $a\in C$ also.

*However*, the statement $a\in B\in \mathcal C$ "looks weird" because "$\in$" is not transitive.   It would seem to imply that $a\in \mathcal C$, which is not necessarily the case.   Thus it is more conventional not to abuse the notation and instead write it in full: $a\in B$ and $B\in \mathcal C$

Answer (score 2):

As the comments have helped me realise, even in this case it is NOT correct to write that $x \in U_i \in \mathcal{T}$.

We could have the case where $X = \{a,b,c\}, \mathcal{T} = \{\varnothing, X, \{a,b\}\}, U = \{a, b\}$. Then $U \in \mathcal{T}$, but $x \in U$ does NOT imply that $x \in \mathcal{T}$.